# Static classes in Delphi (Win32)

Tags: delphi, oop

Is it in Delphi (Win32) possible to declare a whole class (not only a function of the class) as static?

Comment: manually make each and every variable , object and method static (Class var). that's all

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you mean static classes like in .net (and not "static" as in traditional Delphi/Native) - and the answer to that is no.

Comment: Maybe this can help you understand why: Static classes are often used for encapsulation in ways that are similar to units in Delphi.

Comment: I'd prefer not to assume. Can you please make it blatantly obvious what *you* mean by *static*?

Answer (score 12):

Looks like user search for "class functions":

```
type
TSomeClass = class
class procedure MyFunction(...);
```

This is like static method, so, call it:

```
TSomeClass.MyFunction(...);
```

Answer (score 6):

I would use an abstract class (not to be confused with an abstract method in a class) to prevent it from being instantiated instead of demoting the constructor to protected:

```
TMyClass = class abstract
public
  class procedure DoStuff; static;
end;
```

That will enforce the singleton pattern and prevent any instantiations period.

Answer (score 4):

I am not quite sure what you mean by a "static class". You can declare a class, that has only class methods, so these methods can be called without instantiating the class.

```
TSomeClass.SomeMethod;
```

Is that what you want?

Answer (score 2):

Not natively.

Depending on what you need it for, if for the purposes of your code, in some use cases you could replace it with a **Singleton** Pattern object.

For walkthrough on implementing this I'd recommend [this guide](http://www.castle-cadenza.demon.co.uk/single.htm) which, covers almost any version of delphi, but if you're using Delphi 2010 you could also use the new [class Constructors/Destructors](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2009/09/03/38898) for improved results.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a class that contains nothing but static methods.  If you have to maintain some sort of state, then the state variables should be passed as var parameters.  There is no way to "properly" access static variables other than having a set of global variables in the implementation section of the class OUTSIDE the scope of the class, for example:

```
UNIT TestUnit;

INTERFACE

Type
  TStaticClass = Class
  public
    procedure Foo(var Bar:String); static;
  end;

IMPLEMENTATION

var
  LastBar : String; // the last bar
  LastRes : string; // the last result

Procedure TStaticClass.Foo(var Bar:String);
begin
  if Bar <> LastBar then
    LastRes := SomeCPUExpensiveProcess(Bar);
  LastBar := Bar;
  Bar := LastRes;
end;

INITIALIZATION
  LastBar := '';
  LastRes := SomeCPUExpensiveProcess('');
END.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a new unit called uDG_Utils for example, define a class, define a global variable for that class and in the initialization and finalization section you manage the class constructor and destructor.
Now all you need to do is call it like mySuperDuperClass.SuperMethod...

Answer (score 0):

---

EDIT
I have edited this post to remove it.  The answer is admittedly bad and deserves the down-votes.  I don't want it to remain here to confuse or mislead anyone further.

Comment: The fact that you're having to turn hints off should tell you that this is poor code.

Comment: He's asking for a feature that's not supported, so no solution is going to be perfect.

As for hints, I would normally agree and don't condone turning off hints.  The hints are usually right and point out mistakes that can be serious and elusive.  But look closer at this case.  

1- The code produces NO hint in Delphi 7.  So is it poor code in Delphi 2010 but not in Delphi 7?  Well, maybe.

2- The warning is "declared but never used".  If you change the private to protected and seal the class in 2010, .Create is still hidden but the hint goes away.  Does that make it better?  ...

Comment: ... I tend to think not.  But let me be clear; I don't think you're wrong, just that this particular case is a possible exception and that I think it's the lesser of many evils, such as throwing an exception in a public constructor to prevent instantiation.

In any case, even this one, your point is valid and I don't want to discourage anyone from considering it.

Comment: A novel idea. However, I don't think you've ever tested this... **It doesn't work**. The default `constructor TObject.Create();` cannot be "removed"! If you implement a constructor with a different name, `Create()` can still be called. If you implement a constructor with the same name but lower visibility, then the default will be called if yours is out of scope.